# halt the execution till the button is clicked javascript

Tags: javascript

If I have one function which binds some buttons to another function, How can I execute some codes in the same function only after the button is clicked? For example, in below code, button.onclick assigns funct2(this.value) to the button and goes below in the function to execute the remaining code. What I want to achieve is to halt the execution till the some click event happens.

```
function funct1(){

  //some other codes
  button.onclick=function(){funct2(this.value)};

 //CODES TO BE EXECUTED AFTER THE FUNCT2 RESPONDS TO SOME USER CLICK



function funct2(){

//some codes

}
```

Comment: Can you not put all the necessary onclick code into `funct2`? What is the point of leaving it in `funct1`?

Comment: Why not put the "CODES TO BE EXECUTED" into `function funct2()`?

Comment: Thanks guys! ya, now I realize I was not thinking straight. Thanks to you all for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why you are confused about this, try it this way:

Move the code to a third function & call it after the func2 executes...

```
function funct1(){

  //some other codes
  button.onclick=function(){funct2(this.value)};

  function func3() {

  //CODES TO BE EXECUTED AFTER THE FUNCT2 RESPONDS TO SOME USER CLICK

  }

  function funct2(){

  //some codes

  func3();

  }
```

Comment: button.onclick=function(){funct2(this.value);funct3();}; I think it also does the same thing, right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Of course. But moved it into `func2` in case OP would like to call `func3` based on some conditional logic. Just some assumptions...

Answer (score 2):

Whatever code you need to be executed onclick, you must put in `funct2` callback. There is no other way to temporarily 'halt' the execution of javascript and have it restart on certain event.

Comment: That's not quite true. You don't have to put the deferred code *in* `funct2()`. You can also put it in another function that is called *from* `funct2()`, as shown in @loxxy's answer. I'm sure you're familiar with that, it just wasn't clear in your answer and could be a bit misleading for someone who is less familiar with the language. Of course in many cases it would still be simpler to put all the deferred code right there inside `funct2()`, it's just that there is the option of calling another function from there.

Comment: Which is essentially putting it in func2 :)